# Sort a list of Objects by given list of Names that exist

Tags: c++, qt

I have a list of Objects which contain an attribute called 'name'. I want to use a QStringList to sort the list of Objects for those that exist in the QStringList. Otherwise leave the remaining items as is. Because the StringList may not contain strings for every item in the object list.

Would I be best to pass this list of objects into a function and have it return a new list of objects? Below is what I've written. It does not seem like the best approach that is why I posted my question.

```
// list of objects
QList<MyObject> objects;
objects << MyObject("Max")
    << MyObject("Nuke")
    << MyObject("Affinity")
    << MyObject("Photoshop")
    << MyObject("Maya")
    << MyObject("Houdini")
    << MyObject("Google");


// ordered string list
QStringList names = { "Max", "Affinity", "Google" };

QList<MyObject> ListView::sortItems(const QList<MyObject>& objects, const QStringList names)
{
    // New List
    QList<MyObject> newList; // objects that exist in list of "names"
    QList<MyObject> otherList; // objects not listed in "names"

    for (int i=0; i < objects.size(); i++) {
        // Get Objects name
        MyObject obj = objects[i];

        if (names.contains(obj.name())) {
            int index = names.indexOf(obj.name())
            newList.insert(index, obj);
        }else{
            otherList.append(obj);
        }

        // now append the remaining items
        foreach(MyObject obj, otherList) {
            newList.append(obj);
        }
    }
    return newList;
}

// desired output order 
// Max, Affinity, Google, Nuke, Photoshop, Maya, Houdini
```

Comment: @eyllanesc this is not a duplicate when I'm asking about a sorting a list of objects using a ordered list of strings to control the sorting. Not sure how you see this is a duplicate.

Comment: If you check the answer with more upvotes a lambda method is used, there you have to define your own rules and if you need to pass pass data through `[]`

Comment: I'm new to Qt and C++ so I'm not entirely sure how I would go about modifying my example in order to get it to work. That's why i posted on here, for help.